# Firestore document query

Tags: node.js, firebase, search, google-cloud-firestore

So I am using Node JS with firebase firestore, And I would like to create a query in a collection with documents inside of it, every document got the same layout, map (random ID) > map (userID) > {name: "hello"},
So I would like to make a search in the entire collection to find all the objects with the same value of name as a search text, here a image of the database, there is any way to compound this query?
Thanks!!

[image: Snapshot Of database]

Comment: Not sure what you expect us to do with an image of your database. We can't use it to create test tables or data. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I am asking if there is a way to do this query ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the approach you are taking is that second randomId, being random makes it impossible to be handled in a single query, so I would recommend you to change that structure for that purpose, if you change the structure to the following:

```
Desks Collection
    uid
    mapContent subCollection
        mapId
        userId
        color
        name
```

Which is basically the same thing, only organized in a subcollection way, you could query it with this code:

```
var arrayOfMaps = [];

var docRef = db.collection("Desks");

docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    // In case you want to get only the mapContent document
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        arrayOfMaps.push(db.collection("Desks").doc(doc.id).collection("mapContent")
                           .where("name", "==", "Ikea").get());
    });
    // In case you want to get the whole desks document
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        var snapshot = db.collection("Desks").doc(doc.id).collection("mapContent")
                         .where("name", "==", "Ikea").get();
        if (!snapshot.empty){
            arrayOfMaps.push(doc);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks buddy you made me understand the way that structure should be better!